# Concatenate fields of rows with the same ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT mutations.id, genes.loc FROM mutations, genes where mutations.id=genes.id;
```

and outputs this:

```
| SL2.50ch02_51014904 | intergenic    |
| SL2.50ch02_51014907 | upstream      |
| SL2.50ch02_51014907 | downstream    |
| SL2.50ch02_51014907 | intergenic    |
| SL2.50ch02_51014911 | upstream      |
| SL2.50ch02_51014911 | downstream    |
```

My desired output is this:

```
| SL2.50ch02_51014904 | intergenic    |
| SL2.50ch02_51014907 | upstream,downstream,intergenic      |
| SL2.50ch02_51014911 | upstream,downstream      |
```

I thought `GROUP_CONCAT` was useful for this. However, doing this:

```
SELECT mutations.id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(genes.loc)) FROM mutations, genes WHERE mutations.id=genes.id;
```

I have a unique row like this:

```
SL2.50ch02_51014904 | downstream,intergenic,upstream
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `group by`:

```
SELECT m.id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(g.loc)) 
FROM mutations m JOIN
    genes g
    ON m.id = g.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Along the way, you should learn a couple other things:

- Use explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.
- Use table aliases (the `m` and `g`).  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: up for the join and alias usages

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  mutations.id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(genes.loc)) 
FROM 
  mutations, genes 
WHERE 
  mutations.id=genes.id
GROUP BY
  mutations.id
```