# how to use COALESCE in an inner join statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, inner-join, coalesce

im planning to use COALESCE in my problem. All i want is to have values separated by commas in a single column.
here is my statement:

```
select p.[name], cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID
   ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress
   ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod 
FROM CustomerDetails cd 
Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id 
Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

and it will give me this

[image]

now i want the product column to have a result of

```
carbon dioxied,industrial oxygen
```

since they are in the same ID.

please me help me out. thank you so much

UPDATE: fiddle
[image]

UPDATE: current statement but still gives me the same result.

```
use ShoppingCartDB
select 
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.[name]
             FROM  Products p
             WHERE cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Name
     , cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID
     ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress
     ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod 
FROM CustomerDetails cd 
Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id
```

Comment: Check this please; [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986135/concatenate-fields-of-rows-with-the-same-id-in-mysql)

Comment: Do you mean `GROUP_CONCAT`?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat

Comment: hi concat is not recognized, i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.[name]
             FROM  Products p
             WHERE cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Name
     , cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID
     ,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress
     ,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod 
FROM CustomerDetails cd 
Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id
```

Comment: hi sir thank you. no error but it gives me the same result sir. 2 products on the same id has still 2 tables

Comment: I think query needs GroupBy CustomerID.

Comment: Can you setup a SQL Fiddle? Its hard to tell where you going wrong without having access to data.

Comment: i am receiving an error in the fiddle `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[name]
             FROM  Products p
             WHERE cp.ProductID = p.Product' at line 2`

Comment: @ReineViray google SQL Fiddle, go to that website, create your tables schema with some dummy data, click Build Schema button and then copy paste the URL here.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server ??? Select the SQL Server RDBMS in top left corner then build the schema

Comment: im using MSSMS sir

Comment: sql server 2008 sir

Comment: Ok then on SQL Fiddle page on the left top corner there is drop down , select SQL Server 2008 from there and then add the table schema with some data and then click build schema button and copy paste the url here

Comment: i have pasted your answer in the fiddle. gives me an error `create script error`

Comment: @ReineViray copy paste the sql fiddle URL here? lets have a look

Comment: have pasted the image on update sir. please and thank you

Comment: Well you are doing it wrong, where you have put the query itself, you put your Create table scripts there (on the left box) then click Build schema button , then put the query in the right-side box and click Run SQL Button.

Comment: still gives me the same error when i try to create table. what data do you need sir?

Comment: it seems like the statement you provided sir is the right answer but somehow its not giving me the right result :(

Comment: sir please help me

Comment: @ReineViray Sorry cant help you unless I have access to the data itself.

Comment: @ReineViray Do you know what is Team Viewer ? download it install it

Comment: installed sir whats next?

Comment: start team viewer and in Remote Control section copy paste the YourID and password here

Comment: 551 723 646 password is 2304